# Precedence of user-defined bool conversion

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I have a wrapper around a handle (represented as an `int`) which should be usable wherever the handle itself is usable. But I also want to check this easily in `if` conditions. `-1 or <0` is the invalid value. My Idea:

```
#include <cassert>

struct Foo{
    int i;
    Foo(int i): i(i){}
    operator int() const { return i; }
    operator bool() const { return i >= 0; }
};

int main(){
    Foo a(0);
    if(a)
        ;
    else
        assert(false);
    if(!a)
        assert(false);
    assert(!!a);
    Foo b(1);
    assert(!!b);
    assert(b);
    assert(a != b);
    Foo c(-1);
    Foo d(-1);
    assert(!c);
    assert(c==d);
    Foo e(-2);
    assert(c!=e);
}
```

This way I can easily pass a `Foo` to a function taking an `int` and all checks pass. However I'm worried about the precedence of the int conversion over the bool conversion. Is there any? Can I be sure, that `if(Foo(...))`/`if(!Foo(...))`/`if(!!Foo(...))` always takes the bool conversion while direct comparisons take the int conversion so that `Foo(1) != Foo(0)` and `Foo(1) != Foo(2)` is always given?

The standard (C++98) seems not to put an order on bool/int user-defined conversions.

Comment: Do you have to use C++98? C++11 and after provide `explicit` conversion `operator`s, for which ensuring correct conversion to `bool` was one of the main rationales - ensuring we don't end up using some other conversion to another type that _itself_ is convertible to `bool`, which might produce very wrong results when used to make decisions. If you must use older C++, then research the "safe bool" idiom.

Comment: Yes, I need to use C++98. I don't think the safe bool idiom helps here as I still have the int-conversion which might get picked for comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I be sure, that if(Foo(...))/if(!Foo(...))/if(!!Foo(...)) always takes the bool conversion

Yes. `operator!` and the condition of an if statement require the expression to be converted to `bool`. Conversion through `int` requires a user defined conversion to `int`, and then a standard conversion to `bool`. Conversion directly to `bool` requires only that one user defined conversion. One (latter) conversion is preferred to two (former).

> while direct comparisons take the int conversion so that Foo(1) != Foo(0) and Foo(1) != Foo(2) is always given?

No. Both conversions are ranked equally, and it is ambiguous which is intended. An ambiguous conversion makes the program ill-formed.

Solution: Either define `operator==(const Foo&, const Foo&)` and `operator!=(const Foo&, const Foo&)`, or cast explicitly before comparison.

Comment: Alright, this works. Note that g++ does not complain about the ambiguity but clang (3.8) does

Comment: @Flamefire interesting. I think that not showing even a warning in this case is non-conformant to the standard.

Comment: Using g++ 4.8.5. And yes I would have thought so. Not even `-Wall -Wextra` shows anything

Comment: Same for g++ 5.3.0: No warning at all